# Kubernetes pod can't reach overlay network on a specific node

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

I have a k8s cluster deployed on premise on ubuntu 16.04.3 VMs.
Cluster is composed by one master and 3 nodes. Overlay network is flannel.

```
   # kubectl get no
   NAME       STATUS                     ROLES     AGE       VERSION
   buru       Ready                      <none>    70d       v1.8.4
   fraser     Ready,SchedulingDisabled   <none>    2h        v1.8.4
   tasmania   Ready                      <none>    1d        v1.8.4
   whiddy     Ready,SchedulingDisabled   master    244d      v1.8.4
```

Despite being configured exactly the same way, 2 of my nodes (buru and tasmania) work correctly, while the third one (fraser) simply doesn't want to collaborate.

If I ssh in the fraser server, I can correctly reach the overlay network:

```
root@fraser:~# ifconfig flannel.1
flannel.1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:4a:da:84:8a:7b  
          inet addr:10.244.3.0  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::504a:daff:fe84:8a7b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1450  Metric:1
          RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:8 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:756 (756.0 B)  TX bytes:756 (756.0 B)

root@fraser:~# ping 10.244.0.1
PING 10.244.0.1 (10.244.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.244.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.764 ms
^C
--- 10.244.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.764/0.764/0.764/0.000 ms
root@fraser:~# ping 10.244.0.1
PING 10.244.0.1 (10.244.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.244.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.447 ms
64 bytes from 10.244.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.20 ms
64 bytes from 10.244.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.560 ms
^C
--- 10.244.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.447/0.736/1.203/0.334 ms
```

But the pods cannot reach the overlay network apparently:

```
# kubectl --all-namespaces=true get po -o wide | grep fraser
kube-system                  test-fraser                                                 1/1       Running            0          20m       10.244.3.7       fraser

# kubectl -n kube-system exec -ti test-fraser ash
/ # ping 10.244.0.1
PING 10.244.0.1 (10.244.0.1): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 10.244.0.1 ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

The `test-fraser` pod is just an alpine static pod I am using for troubleshooting.

The same pod, deployed the same way in another node (buru) works just fine.

Since overlay network works on the host itself, I'd say that flannel is working just fine here.
For some reason, though, networking inside pods isn't working.

**Other notes**

- All server have no firewall enabled
- Docker version is the same (1.13.1)
- All nodes are up to date in terms of ubuntu updates

Can anybody help me troubleshoot this problem?

**edit**

```
kubectl describe no fraser
Name:               fraser
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=fraser
Annotations:        flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-data={"VtepMAC":"52:4a:da:84:8a:7b"}
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-type=vxlan
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/kube-subnet-manager=true
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip=80.211.157.110
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl=0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach=true
Taints:             <none>
CreationTimestamp:  Thu, 07 Dec 2017 12:51:22 +0100
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  OutOfDisk        False   Thu, 07 Dec 2017 15:27:27 +0100   Thu, 07 Dec 2017 12:51:22 +0100   KubeletHasSufficientDisk     kubelet has sufficient disk space available
  MemoryPressure   False   Thu, 07 Dec 2017 15:27:27 +0100   Thu, 07 Dec 2017 14:47:57 +0100   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Thu, 07 Dec 2017 15:27:27 +0100   Thu, 07 Dec 2017 14:47:57 +0100   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  Ready            True    Thu, 07 Dec 2017 15:27:27 +0100   Thu, 07 Dec 2017 14:48:07 +0100   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status. AppArmor enabled
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  80.211.157.110
  Hostname:    fraser
Capacity:
 cpu:     4
 memory:  8171244Ki
 pods:    110
Allocatable:
 cpu:     4
 memory:  8068844Ki
 pods:    110
System Info:
 Machine ID:                 cb102c57fd539a2fb8ffab52578f27bd
 System UUID:                423E50F4-C4EF-23F0-F300-B568F4B4B8B1
 Boot ID:                    ca80d640-380a-4851-bab0-ee1fffd20bb2
 Kernel Version:             4.4.0-92-generic
 OS Image:                   Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
 Operating System:           linux                                                                                                                                                                                
 Architecture:               amd64                                                                                                                                                                                
 Container Runtime Version:  docker://1.13.1                                                                                                                                                                      
 Kubelet Version:            v1.8.4                                                                                                                                                                               
 Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.8.4                                                                                                                                                                               
PodCIDR:                     10.244.3.0/24                                                                                                                                                                        
ExternalID:                  fraser                                                                                                                                                                               
Non-terminated Pods:         (5 in total)                                                                                                                                                                         
  Namespace                  Name                                         CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits                                                                                
  ---------                  ----                                         ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------                                                                                
  kube-system                filebeat-mghqx                               100m (2%)     0 (0%)      100Mi (1%)       200Mi (2%)                                                                                   
  kube-system                kube-flannel-ds-gvw4s                        0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)                                                                                       
  kube-system                kube-proxy-62vts                             0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)                                                                                       
  kube-system                test-fraser                                  0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)                                                                                       
  prometheus                 prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-mwq67    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)                                                                                       
Allocated resources:                                                                                                                                                                                              
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)                                                                                                                                                    
  CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits                                                                                                                                                        
  ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------                                                                                                                                                        
  100m (2%)     0 (0%)      100Mi (1%)       200Mi (2%)                                                                                                                                                           
Events:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  Type    Reason                   Age                From                Message
  ----    ------                   ----               ----                -------
  Normal  Starting                 48m                kubelet, fraser     Starting kubelet.
  Normal  NodeAllocatableEnforced  48m                kubelet, fraser     Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
  Normal  NodeHasSufficientDisk    48m                kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeHasSufficientDisk
  Normal  NodeHasSufficientMemory  48m                kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal  NodeHasNoDiskPressure    48m                kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal  NodeNotReady             48m                kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeNotReady
  Normal  NodeNotSchedulable       48m                kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeNotSchedulable
  Normal  NodeReady                48m                kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeReady
  Normal  NodeNotSchedulable       48m                kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeNotSchedulable
  Normal  NodeAllocatableEnforced  48m                kubelet, fraser     Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
  Normal  NodeHasSufficientDisk    48m                kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeHasSufficientDisk
  Normal  NodeHasSufficientMemory  48m                kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal  Starting                 48m                kubelet, fraser     Starting kubelet.
  Normal  NodeNotReady             48m                kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeNotReady
  Normal  NodeHasNoDiskPressure    48m                kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal  NodeReady                48m                kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeReady
  Normal  Starting                 39m                kubelet, fraser     Starting kubelet.
  Normal  NodeAllocatableEnforced  39m                kubelet, fraser     Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
  Normal  NodeHasSufficientDisk    39m                kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeHasSufficientDisk
  Normal  NodeHasSufficientMemory  39m (x2 over 39m)  kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal  NodeHasNoDiskPressure    39m (x2 over 39m)  kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal  NodeNotReady             39m                kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeNotReady
  Normal  NodeNotSchedulable       39m                kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeNotSchedulable
  Normal  NodeReady                39m                kubelet, fraser     Node fraser status is now: NodeReady
  Normal  Starting                 39m                kube-proxy, fraser  Starting kube-proxy.
```

Comment: hi, can you run following command `kubectl describe nodes fraser `?

Comment: Sure, added to the original question

Comment: Everything seems fine, As I understood there might be something with IPTABLES which is throwing away packets.  Could you verify and validate the IPtables ?

Comment: That was it! The "FORWARD" chain had "DROP" as policy. Thanks a lot (please post an answer, I'll accept it)

Comment: Done :) your welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been answered in the comment sections.

for debugging k8s Node, we need to make sure following components (Kubelet,Docker,Kube-proxy and IPtables) work perfectly.

we can get comprehensive information by the following command

```
kubectl get nodes 
kubectl describe nodes NODE-NAME
```

By the comprehensive result, we can check kube-proxy, kubelet , docker and CNI plugin (flannel) are running perfectly.

If its networking issues we will check IPtables

```
iptables -L -v
```